# Cygwin/X x11 forwarding from Raspberry Pi to Windows

Tags: opengl, raspberry-pi, cygwin, sdl, x11-forwarding

I have figured out how to use x11 forwarding, and it's working for most things I've tried with. But the one main C program I'm trying to launch hangs up in the terminal when I try to run it in Cygwin on my Windows machine.

In the `draw.c` part of the program it says I should see `init_SDL` `init_gl` `init_fft` `init_ftdi` in my terminal when it runs, then the GUI appear, but when I run this in cygwin, it prints `init_SDL` then hangs. (https://github.com/bear24rw/rgb_table/blob/master/code/table_drivers/beat_finder/draw.c) this is the piece of code that shows what should output to my terminal, not the main.c that I actually run.

When I run the code through a VNC on the Pi's desktop, it runs but it's choppy. I'd like to be able to have it forward only the GUI part of my code to the Windows machine. The other code I need I've tried this with does exactly what I want it to do so I'm not sure why this one in particular doesn't work.
I've tried several options from YouTube/Google, I've tried just about every VNC, tried Xming and puTTY, I do have all the packages installed for Cygwin that I need I believe. I'm not sure if I need to change part of the code to be able to run or what.

### Update

When I SSH from my Linux machine to the Pi and run the code, it works. So why not on my Windows machine with all the same packages?

Answer (score 0):

I was missing a command. When I log into the pi, I need to run `xauth merge /home/pi/.Xauthority` then the code runs!